# how to verify an iCloud ID token against iCloud?

Tags: ios, authentication, mobile, icloud

I was [just reading](https://medium.com/@skreutzb/ios-onboarding-without-signup-screens-cb7a76d01d6e) about using iCloud ID tokens for app identification on mobile devices.

If my server receives a request over the internet with an iCloud ID token, is there a way for it to verify that it was issued by Apple and wasn't just made up by the sending party?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Device Check Framework.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) "Access per-device, per-developer data that your associated server can use in its business logic." It was suggested in a recent comment on an answer in [this SO thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/how-to-safeguard-a-rest-api-for-only-trusted-mobile-applications).

This is how to use Device Check with an iCloud user ID hash to make sure requests to your API are legitimate. A lot of the following code was adapted from [this](https://github.com/marinosoftware/DeviceCheckSample/blob/master/app/MarinoDeviceCheck/ViewController.swift).

1. Get an ephemeral Device Check token from Apple in your iOS app, then send it with your requests to your backend along with an iCloud user name hash.

   In Swift 4:

   ```
   import DeviceCheck

   let currDevice = DCDevice.current

   if ViewController.currDevice.isSupported {
       ViewController.currDevice.generateToken { (data, error) in
           if let data = data {
               let url = "your-url"
               let sesh = URLSession(configuration: .default)
               var req = URLRequest(url: url)
               req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
               req.httpMethod = "POST"
               DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                   var jsonObj = [
                       "deviceCheckToken" : data.base64EncodedString(), 
                       "iCloudUserNameHash": self.iCloudUserID,
                       "moreParams": "moreParamsHere"
                   ]
                   let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: [])
                   req.httpBody = data
                   let task = sesh.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                       if let data = data, let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers), let jsonDictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any]  {
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               // Process response here
                           }
                       }
                   })
                   task.resume()
               }
           } else if let error = error {
               print("Error when generating a token:", error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
   } else {
       print("Platform is not supported. Make sure you aren't running in an emulator.")
   }
   ```
2. You can store two bits per device per app in the Device Check framework. Use bit0 to remember that you've already served requests to the current device. First call the Device Check validation endpoint to see if the request originates from an iOS app - as opposed to, for instance, someone's terminal. Next, use the Device Check query endpoint to get the two Device Check bits for the current device. If bit0 is true, then assume this device already has at least one row in your requests table keyed on the given iCloud user name hash. If there is such a row, this is probably a legitimate request because it would be hard to guess other keys. If there is no such row, the user probably generated a fake iCloud user hash. However, if bit0 is false, then this device hasn't put a row in the requests table yet. Put a row keyed on the given iCloud user name hash and set bit0 to true for this device with the Device Check update endpoint. Here's an example in Node 8.10 in an AWS Lambda, where the requests table lives in DynamoDB.

   **endpoint.js**

   ```
   const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   const utf8 = require('utf8');

   const asyncAWS = require('./lib/awsPromiseWrappers');
   const deviceCheck = require('./lib/deviceCheck');
   const util = require('./lib/util');

   // AWS globals
   const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
       region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
   });
   const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

   // Apple Device Check keys
   const cert = utf8.encode([
       process.env.BEGIN_PRIVATE_KEY,
       process.env.APPLE_DEVICE_CHECK_CERT,
       process.env.END_PRIVATE_KEY,
   ].join('\n'));  // utf8 encoding and newlines are necessary for jwt to do job
   const keyId = process.env.APPLE_DEVICE_CHECK_KEY_ID;
   const teamId = process.env.APPLE_ITUNES_CONNECT_TEAM_ID;

   // Return true if device check succeeds
   const isLegitDevice = async (deviceCheckToken, iCloudUserNameHash) => {

       // Pick the correct (dev or prod) Device Check API URL
       var deviceCheckHost;
       if (process.env.STAGE === 'dev') {
           deviceCheckHost = process.env.DEV_DEVICE_CHECK_API_URL;
       } else if (stage === 'prod') {
           deviceCheckHost = process.env.PROD_DEVICE_CHECK_API_URL;
       } else {
           util.cloudwatchLog(`--> Unrecognized stage ${stage}. Aborting DC`);
           return;
       }

       // Make sure device is valid. If not, return false
       try {
           await deviceCheck.validateDevice(
               cert, keyId, teamId, deviceCheckToken, deviceCheckHost);
       } catch (err) {
           util.cloudwatchLog(`--> DC validation failed. ${err}`);
           return false;
       }

       // Query for Device Check bits
       var dcQueryResults;
       try {
           dcQueryResults = await deviceCheck.queryTwoBits(
               cert, keyId, teamId, deviceCheckToken, deviceCheckHost);
       } catch (err) {
           dcQueryResults = null;
       }

       // If bit0 is true, then this device already has at least one row in the
       // search counts table
       if (dcQueryResults && dcQueryResults.bit0) {

           // Try to get the counts row keyed on given user name
           const getParams = {
               TableName: process.env.SEARCH_COUNTS_TABLE,
               Key: { u: iCloudUserNameHash },
           };
           var countsRow;
           try {
               countsRow = await asyncAWS.invokeDynamoDBGet(dynamodb, getParams);
           } catch (err) {
               const msg = `--> Couldn't get counts row during DC call: ${err}`;
               util.cloudwatchLog(msg);
               return false;
           }

           // If it doesn't exist, return false
           if (!countsRow) {
               return false;
           } else {  // if it DOES exist, this is a legit request
               return true;
           }
       } else {

           // Initialize the row in memory
           const secsSinceEpoch = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
           const countsRow = {
               h: [0, secsSinceEpoch],
               d: [0, secsSinceEpoch],
               w: [0, secsSinceEpoch],
               m: [0, secsSinceEpoch],
               y: [0, secsSinceEpoch],
               a: 0,
               u: iCloudUserNameHash,
           };

           // Put it in the search counts table
           const putParams = {
               Item: countsRow,
               TableName: process.env.SEARCH_COUNTS_TABLE,
           };
           try {
               await asyncAWS.invokeDynamoDBPut(dynamodb, putParams);
           } catch (err) {
               const msg = `--> Couldn't set counts row in DC call: ${err}`
               util.cloudwatchLog(msg);
               return false;
           }

           // Set the device check bit
           try {
               await deviceCheck.updateTwoBits(true, false,
                   cert, keyId, teamId, deviceCheckToken, deviceCheckHost);
           } catch (err) {
               const msg = `--> DC update failed. ${iCloudUserNameHash} ${err}`;
               util.cloudwatchLog(msg);
               return false;
           }

           // If we got here, the request was legit
           return true;
       }
   };

   exports.main = async (event, context, callback) => {

       // Handle inputs
       const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
       const iCloudUserNameHash = body.iCloudUserNameHash;
       const deviceCheckToken = body.deviceCheckToken;
       const otherParams = body.otherParams;

       // If allowed to search, increment search counts then search
       var deviceCheckSucceeded;
       try {
           deviceCheckSucceeded =
               await isLegitDevice(deviceCheckToken, iCloudUserNameHash);
       } catch (err) {
           util.cloudwatchLog(`--> Error checking device: ${err}`);
           return callback(null, resp.failure({}));
       }

       if (deviceCheckSucceeded) {

           // Do your stuff here

           return callback(null, resp.success({}));
       } else {
           return callback(null, resp.failure({}));
       }
   };
   ```

   **deviceCheck.js**

   ```
   const https = require('https');
   const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
   const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

   const util = require('../lib/util');

   // Set the two Device Check bits for this device.
   // Params:
   //   bit0 (boolean) - true if never seen given iCloud user ID
   //   bit1 (boolean) - TODO not used yet
   //   cert (string) - Device Check certificate. Get from developer.apple.com)
   //   keyId (string) - Part of metadata for Device Check certificate)
   //   teamId (string) - My developer team ID. Can be found in iTunes Connect
   //   dcToken (string) - Ephemeral Device Check token passed from frontend
   //   deviceCheckHost (string) - API URL, which is either for dev or prod env
   const updateTwoBits = async (
       bit0, bit1, cert, keyId, teamId, dcToken, deviceCheckHost) => {

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           var jwToken = jwt.sign({}, cert, {
               algorithm: 'ES256',
               keyid: keyId,
               issuer: teamId,
           });

           var postData = {
               'device_token' : dcToken,
               'transaction_id': uuidv4(),
               'timestamp': Date.now(),
               'bit0': bit0,
               'bit1': bit1,
           }

           var postOptions = {
               host: deviceCheckHost,
               port: '443',
               path: '/v1/update_two_bits',
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwToken,
               },
           };

           var postReq = https.request(postOptions, function(res) {
               res.setEncoding('utf8');

               var data = '';
               res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                   data += chunk;
               });

               res.on('end', function() {
                   util.cloudwatchLog(
                       `--> Update bits done with status code ${res.statusCode}`);
                   resolve();
               });

               res.on('error', function(data) {
                   util.cloudwatchLog(
                       `--> Error ${res.statusCode} in update bits: ${data}`);
                   reject();
               });
           });

           postReq.write(new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(postData)));
           postReq.end();
       });
   };

   // Query the two Device Check bits for this device.
   // Params:
   //     cert (string) - Device Check certificate. Get from developer.apple.com)
   //     keyId (string) - Part of metadata for Device Check certificate)
   //     teamId (string) - My developer team ID. Can be found in iTunes Connect
   //     dcToken (string) - Ephemeral Device Check token passed from frontend
   //     deviceCheckHost (string) - API URL, which is either for dev or prod env
   // Return:
   //     { bit0 (boolean), bit1 (boolean), lastUpdated (String) }
   const queryTwoBits = async (cert, keyId, teamId, dcToken, deviceCheckHost) => {

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

           var jwToken = jwt.sign({}, cert, {
               algorithm: 'ES256',
               keyid: keyId,
               issuer: teamId,
           });

           var postData = {
               'device_token' : dcToken,
               'transaction_id': uuidv4(),
               'timestamp': Date.now(),
           }

           var postOptions = {
               host: deviceCheckHost,
               port: '443',
               path: '/v1/query_two_bits',
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwToken,
               },
           };

           var postReq = https.request(postOptions, function(res) {
               res.setEncoding('utf8');

               var data = '';
               res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                   data += chunk;
               });

               res.on('end', function() {
                   try {
                       var json = JSON.parse(data);
                       resolve({
                           bit0: json.bit0,
                           bit1: json.bit1,
                           lastUpdated: json.last_update_time,
                       });
                   } catch (e) {
                       const rc = res.statusCode;
                       util.cloudwatchLog(
                           `--> DC query call failed. ${e}, ${data}, ${rc}`);
                       reject();
                   }
               });

               res.on('error', function(data) {
                   const code = res.statusCode;
                   util.cloudwatchLog(
                       `--> Error ${code} with query bits call: ${data}`);
                   reject();
               });
           });

           postReq.write(new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(postData)));
           postReq.end();
       });
   };

   // Make sure devie is valid.
   // Params:
   //   cert (string) - Device Check certificate. Get from developer.apple.com)
   //   keyId (string) - Part of metadata for Device Check certificate)
   //   teamId (string) - My developer team ID. Can be found in iTunes Connect
   //   dcToken (string) - Ephemeral Device Check token passed from frontend
   //   deviceCheckHost (string) - API URL, which is either for dev or prod env
   const validateDevice = async (
       cert, keyId, teamId, dcToken, deviceCheckHost) => {

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           var jwToken = jwt.sign({}, cert, {
               algorithm: 'ES256',
               keyid: keyId,
               issuer: teamId,
           });

           var postData = {
               'device_token' : dcToken,
               'transaction_id': uuidv4(),
               'timestamp': Date.now(),
           }

           var postOptions = {
               host: deviceCheckHost,
               port: '443',
               path: '/v1/validate_device_token',
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwToken,
               },
           };

           var postReq = https.request(postOptions, function(res) {
               res.setEncoding('utf8');

               var data = '';
               res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                   data += chunk;
               });

               res.on('end', function() {
                   util.cloudwatchLog(
                       `--> DC validation done w/ status code ${res.statusCode}`);
                   if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                       resolve();
                   } else {
                       reject();
                   }
               });

               res.on('error', function(data) {
                   util.cloudwatchLog(
                       `--> Error ${res.statusCode} in DC validate: ${data}`);
                   reject();
               });
           });

           postReq.write(new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(postData)));
           postReq.end();
       });
   };

   exports.updateTwoBits = updateTwoBits;
   exports.queryTwoBits = queryTwoBits;
   exports.validateDevice = validateDevice;
   ```